# Quaternion.AngleAxis smallest value?

Tags: unity, quaternion

If I'm using an angle with a value of somewhat below 0.1 degrees in Quaternion.AngleAxis, the quaternion will not apply a rotation at all. Why is this?

Comment: We generally won't be able to answer "why" questions about the reasons software written by someone else works the way it does. What we *can* do is answer "how" questions about how you can make *your game* work, despite whatever obstacle you've found. Try editing your question to ask about the game feature you're using this to accomplish, and we can help you find ways to ensure it works as desired.

Comment: @DMGregory I can find another way to make my game work, I just found this behaviour really peculiar and thought there must be some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you slowly decrement the angle bit by bit and print the resulting quaternion in round-trip precision, you'll notice that eventually the w component rounds to 1. This corresponds to the identity quaternion, ie. "no rotation".

The formula for the w component is \$\cos \frac \theta 2\$ where your angle is \$\theta\$. So we can use that to find the angle where this would have to round to 1 when stored in a 32-bit float.

We have 23 bits of mantissa, which means we need the result to be within \$2^{-24}\$ of 1 to round up. That means at or above \$\frac {16777215} {16777216} \approx 0.999999940395355\$.

We can find the critical angle at which that happens as...

$$\theta^* = 2 \cos^{-1} \left( \frac {16777215} {16777216} \right) \approx 0.039564682° $$

So, angles of rotation less than about 0.04 degrees just aren't accurately representable with single-precision floating point.

(Unity actually gets a bit further than this - not rounding to 1 until we're down to 0.02797646°. That may have to do with how it normalizes the quaternion)

Fortunately, for any object less than 2896 pixels in diameter, a rotation at this angle or less amounts to less than a pixel of difference in a rendered image, and so it gets rounded out by our rasterization or antialiasing anyway, so in practice this isn't really the limiting factor in the precision to which we can express orientation in a rendered game frame.

Comment: I've tested what you said and that seems to be true. for values of 0.02 degrees and smaller. However I see that the W value isn't exactly 1 for a value of 0.08 degrees, yet it produces no rotation when a vector is multiplied by it.

Comment: This I am not able to reproduce. Rotating `Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward) * Vector3.up` produces a result numerically distinct from `(0, 1, 0)` down past `0.0000000001°`, which is as far as I've checked yet. I'd suspect your particular choice of vectors might be running into similar rounding issues due to floating point precision, or you may be comparing/printing approximate values. Keep in mind the default comparer for `Vector3` is approximate, and the default printing behaviour can round-off precision present in the float.

Comment: So I found strange behaviour. I didn't test my solution numerically before (in the same way you did), and I did in fact get two separate vectors when rotating. I even get separate vectors for values far below 0.02. (Which is strange, assuming your explanation?)

Where the bug seemed to be, is in how I applied this rotation. I did transform.up = newOrientation. This seems to have some precision issues. It's fixed when I use transform.rotation = frameRotation * transform.rotation

Comment: I wrote my answer based on when w hit 1 because that was the highest angular threshold I could find. The z component of my quaternion continues to take on distinct values beyond that 0.02 range, and that can change the result of the multiplication. In future, you might want to include your specific code or test case in your question, so answers can reproduce and target the particular symptoms you're observing without guessing. 

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your help!